# Custom Json Converter with dependecy

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, json.net

I have to use a custom `JsonConverter` with ASP.NET Core for a reason, and I need to use it with `JsonInputFormatter`. The only way I've found is to use `AddJsonOption` extension method like this:

```
services
  .AddMvc()
  .AddJsonOptions(jso => jso.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter()))
```

But it has a flaw: `CustomConverter` requires a dependency from a DI container which cannot be easily solved at configuration time. 
So the question: is there any programmer friendly way to supply a `JsonConverter` with dependency to ASP.NET Core `JsonInputFormatter`?

Answer (score 2):

One quick workaround would be to postpone it to the `Configure` method.

```
public Confiugre(IAppBuilder app, IOptions<MvcOptions> mvcOptions, IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> jsonOptions) 
{
    var formatter = mvcOptions.InputFormatters.OfType<JsonInputFormatter>().Single();
    jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
        new CustomConverter(formatter));

    ...
}
```

Still feels a bit dirty though ;)